# Adaptive Cards 1.2 in Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

Do you know if is planned to integrate the adaptive cards version 1.2 in Microsoft Teams? And if yes when are you planning to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Teams currently supports v1.0 of Adaptive Cards, with additional support for newer versions planned. We'll update this page when support is added: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/whats-new

Answer (score 0):

Adaptive Cards 1.2 in Teams are GA

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/adaptive-cards-1-2-are-ga-in-microsoft-teams/